# Applets opening separate consoles, driving me crazy. Leading to other issues

Tags: java, applet, japplet, unsatisfiedlinkerror

What could cause applets in a plugin cached jar to open separate java consoles? I have 3 applets for a DDE server/client, the first loads the required files, the second starts the server and the third starts a client to send a command to a desktop app. The 1st and 3rd applets print to a console and the second opens it's own console.

This is causing problems in the form of UnsatisfiedLinkErrors as the native dde client library is being used concurrently.

I know this is not much to go on, but I'm stumped.

**UPDATE**
The problem is corrected when I use JS alerts in the JSP page that's home to the applets, see below.

1) index.jsp includes an applet tag for the `InstallDDEFiles` applet, plugin cached. When `InstallDDEFiles` applet verifies the required DDE libraries are placed in the JRE, it sets an instance variable `installed = true`.

2) In $(document).ready, I call the `InstallDDEFiles` getter for `installed`, and if true, I add source to an iframe on the page with the applet tag for the `DDEServer` with `document.getElementByID().src = ''`. The `DDEServer` applet is in the same jar as the `InstallDDEFiles`.

The following results in 2 separate java consoles opening, which leads to `UnsatisfiedLinkErrors` further along in the process when I try to load the DLLs for DDE. 
Now, if I add an alert() with the results of the `InstallDDEFiles.isInstalled()` just after it's called, the applets print in the same console, and I don't get the `UnsatisfiedLinkErrors` I normally get. If I simply log the results of the `isInstalled()` call, I see the correct value of `true` but I still get the 2 consoles and still get the link error.

Comment: What are these 'consoles' you are referring to?  DMY the system command line?  This question really makes no sense to me as it stands.

Comment: Java consoles, the standard out for applets, displayed by selecting 'Show Console' in the java cpl for Java used by the browser. I know this is vague, but I've seen others having the same issue and no real answers. Totally stumped... I'll answer any specifics, just don't know where to start.

Comment: Refer to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_execution.html#jre) to try to get them all running in one JVM (== one console).

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that clears it up. With both applets communicating with JS there was some blocking going on. I'll investigate more to find exactly how to get it ironed out but I am on the right track.